# VSCode Formatting On Save Despite Setting Being Unchecked

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code

**tl;dr** - how to fix (disable) formatting on save when the "Format On Save" option is already unchecked?

Every time I save a file in VSCode, it automatically formats it, despite the "Format On Save" option being checked off. I've tried re-checking and un-checking the setting, restarting VSCode, and clearing my default formatter.

**Before Save**

[image]

**After Save (Ctrl + s)**

[image]

**User (and Workspace) Settings**
[image]

**Note**: Although my code in the example uses LightningElement, this issue is occurring with non-SFDX projects as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug, I'm not sure but you need to change `format on save` to be false both in the `user` and `JSON` settings.

In the command bar (`Ctrl` `Shift` `P`) type:

```
> Open settings (JSON)
```

This should take you to the `JSON` config file where **you need to add/change this line:**

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
```